# Weka Extract coefficients

Tags: weka

After I apply PCA to reduce dimension using method reduceDimensionality, I got the the result as name of attributes of returned instances like ax+by+cz...(string).

Do I myself have to parse the string to get coefficients or is there other ways?

Thanks,
TT

Comment: Do you use the UI or the Java API? If the UI, perhaps you should try the API?

Comment: Hi, I use API. I have parsed the values by naming attributes with the special keyword such as =Attribute_name; (; to split value=Attribute_name pairs and = to get the value).